# MySQL Workbench -Max()

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy aprendiendo a usar MySQL Workbench y veo que hay algo que mis compañeros de curso con sus computadoras pueden hacer y yo no con la mía. (También puede que este haciendo algo mal)

En este caso es lo siguiente:
Tengo una base de datos con 10 columnas, las 3 que me interesan son usuario saldo y sexo. 
Quiero mostrar el valor máximo de Saldo para Mujeres y que me diga a que Usuario pertenece. 
Intente con el siguiente código (que funciona en compañeros pero no en mi):

```
use Celulares;
select Usuario, max(Saldo) from TablaUsuarios where Sexo='M' ;
```

Answer (score 1):

A ver..:

> Quiero mostrar el valor máximo de Saldo para Mujeres y que me diga a
>   que Usuario pertenece

Así obtenemos el Saldo máximo de las mujeres:

```
select max(Saldo) 
       from TablaUsuarios 
       where Sexo='M'
```

Ahora, para saber el usuario, deberíamos ver a que usuario pertenece dicho saldo:

```
select usuario
       from TablaUsuarios 
       where Sexo='M'
             and Saldo = (select max(Saldo) 
                                 from TablaUsuarios 
                                 where Sexo='M')
```

Comentarios:

- Hay otras, y tal vez mejores formas de hacerlo, pero esta es bien estándar
- En caso que tuvieras dos usuarias con el mismo saldo máximo la consulta te retornará ambas.

Answer (score 0):

La consulta no está bien construida ya que MySQL permite ciertas prácticas que no deberia:

- Al usar una función de agrupación como `MAX` entonces debes hacer al final una agrupación por el resto de columnas que tengas en el `SELECT`

Entonces debe quedar así:

```
select Usuario, 
       max(Saldo) 
from TablaUsuarios 
where Sexo='M' 
GROUP by Usuario;
```

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias por sus respuestas!

Estuve leyendo y encontre con que deberia desactivar Full group by desde la linea de comandos (terminal).

Con eso ahora no tengo problemas.

Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Aquí sólo van las respuestas a tu pregunta. Si tienes que añadir algo a tu pregunta, edítala.